# Map the elements of bi-dimensional array ignoring the last sub-array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let say that there is this matrix:

```
myArray = [["a", 6, 5.54, "b"],
           ["xxx", 65.5, 45],
           [343, "abc", 0.09]];
```

My goal is to compute the sum of each sub-array but ignoring the last sub-array, it this case `[343, "abc", 0.09]`. Also, ignoring the string values.

I managed to do it for all the sub-arrays and it looks like this:

```js
myArray = [["a", 6, 5.54, "b"],
           ["xxx", 65.5, 45],
           [343, "abc", 0.09]];

result = myArray.map(a => a.reduce((s, v) => s + (+v || 0), 0));
console.log(result)
```

Don't know which condition to add in order to ignore the last sub-array.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do that with `.map()`, because it's intended to be used to produce a value for every element of the source array. You could use `.reduce()` instead, and just not change the accumulator in the last call to the callback.

Comment: The `reduce` function also takes two additional arguments: the index and the array. That should get you what you need to determine whether you're on the last index.

Comment: That's easily done with a simple loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `slice(0, -1)`.

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.
>
> **Second param:**
>   A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(2,-1) extracts the third element through the second-to-last element in the sequence.

```js
var myArray = [
  ["a", 6, 5.54, "b"],
  ["xxx", 65.5, 45],
  [343, "abc", 0.09]
];

var result = myArray.slice(0, -1).map(a => a.reduce((s, v) => s + (+v || 0), 0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd do it that way (if it is always the last element, remove it using `pop()`):

```js
myArray = [["a", 6, 5.54, "b"],
           ["xxx", 65.5, 45],
           [343, "abc", 0.09]];
           
myArray.pop()

result = myArray.map(a => a.reduce((s, v) => s + (+v || 0), 0));
 
console.log(result)
```